# How can I sign a dylib using just a normal apple id account? (No developer account yet)

Tags: ios, macos, dylib, codesign, mach-o

I have a dylib and in order for the it to be able to run on my machine, I had to disable library validation in the target settings on xcode. Is it possible to get it signed without a paid developer account just for testing purposes? Any links or tutorials on how to go about doing that would help a great deal.

Comment: Yeah [looks like it](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/).

Comment: Any tutorial on how do I go about signing it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depends on how you're getting the library.

**Building in Xcode**

If building in Xcode, you should be able to enable signing and tell it to use `Team` `None` and `Sign to Run Locally` all in the `Signing and Capabilities` pane of the Project.

**Signing an existing dylib**

If you're not building it in Xcode and you want to sign a binary you've built or retrieved in some other manner, you're going to need to use `codesign`, which can be pretty complex.

You can theoretically run codesign using any certificate that has been authorized for code signing, and you can create that with a self-signed certificate, but that is a supreme pain in the neck, and not certain to result in success.

Xcode should automatically create a "Mac Developer" code signing certificate if you have signed in to the developer portal and allowed Xcode to manage signing identifies for you.

You can verify that you have a codesigning identity by using:

```
security find-identity -v -p codesigning
```

This will list all of the valid codesigning identities.

Signing the `dylib` is a matter of using the codesign command:

```
codesign --force --timestamp --sign <name of certificate> <binary you want to sign>
```

**Using a self-signed code-signing certificate**

Note: this is not recommended, but it did work for me.

1. Start Keychain Access
2. Choose **Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Create a Certificate...**
3. Name your certificate something easy to type
4. Change the **Certificate Type** to **Code Signing**
5. Click **Create**
6. Click **Continue** after reading the warning
7. Click **Done** when it completes (and go back to Keychain Access)
8. Find your newly-created certificate in Keychain Access and double-click on it to get the details
9. Click the disclosure triangle next to **Trust** to expose the trust preferences
10. Set **When using this certificate** to **Always Trust**

Now, your self-signed certificate should show up when you run the aforementioned `security` command to list out the codesigning certificates. If it does, you most likely didn't set the **Always Trust** or the certificate type to **Code Signing**.

At this point, you're ready to execute the code signing command, and then you can verify using:

```
codesign -vvvv <path to dylib>
```