# How to sign a dylib for iOS from within CMake

Tags: ios, cmake, code-signing

We are working on a cross platform project which has a core library written in C++.

I am able to build this library with CMake using an iOS toolchain.

However, I have just discovered the need to sign the dylib for it to be usable on an iPad.

So ... search, search ... search again.

No, I have not found clear instructions as to what needs to be added to my CMakeLists.txt file to setup and run code signing after the dylib has been created.

I have seen [CMake and Code Signing in XCode 8 for iOS projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664125/cmake-and-code-signing-in-xcode-8-for-ios-projects), but it seems incomplete, as code signing is not run at the end of the make.

So, what steps do I need to add to my CMake process to enable and run code signing for iOS ?

I have :

- CMake 3.18.3
- XCode version 11.6
- XCode already has a provisioning profile declared, but I want to use automatic provisioning (*if that makes sense*)
- iOS toolchain file from google

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `codesign`?

Comment: I do not know how to use it correctly - which is why I am requesting the information

Comment: Look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61176509/979986